# Python: understanding (None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)

Tags: python

James Powell, in his short description for an upcoming presentation, says he is the proud inventor of one of the gnarliest Python one-liners:

```
(None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)
```

I am trying to figure out this generator, and since I live with Python 2.7.x, I'm also tripping over the `(yield from g)` expression.

How do I read this, and what would be the python 2.7.x analog?

---

What a great discussion below! I want to check if I have this correct in the main.

```
>>> l = [10, 11, iter(xrange(5)), 12, 13]
>>> g = iter(l)
>>> flat_g = (None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)
>>> list(flat_g)
[10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13]
```

Is that about right?

Comment: That is indeed gnarly. The full equivalence of `yield from g` in Python can be found in the [generator delegation PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) and it's perhaps a little longer than needed here.

Comment: I wonder whether using ``yield from`` in a generator expression was actually intended.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: it was absolutely intended. `yield from` is an *expression*. It returns a value; that of the `StopIteration()` exception raised by the generator that was delegated to.

Comment: I doubt that this behaviour can be recreated fully in Python 2.7. You can flatten the generator but not take advantage of the generator delegation optimizations that the new syntax allows for.

Comment: one final question (off topic): does `yield from g` yield a single item from `g`, or yield all items from `g` before continuing?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: it delegates to `g`; the current generator is paused until all items from `g` have been yielded. So whatever is looping over the generator produced by `(None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)` is looping over `g` instead, until exhausted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This expression seems to be a code-golf way of writing:

```
(a for b in g for a in b)
```

((Or maybe the motivation be taking advantage of generator delegations, but IMHO readability really suffers.))

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.3

g = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

a = (None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)
for x in a: print (x)

b = (a for b in g for a in b)
for x in b: print (x)
```

Prints twice the flattened list.

I think it becomes more legible if you use different variable names:

```
(None for sublist in g if (yield from sublist) and False)
```

Which is the same as

```
(42 for sublist in g if (yield from sublist) and False)
```

as due to the `something and False` the outer generator doesn't yield anything, while the inner generator yields all elements of all sublists (subgenerators, subiterables).

Maybe this clarifies a bit how it works:

```
('Sublist {}'.format(idx) for idx, sublist in enumerate(g) if (yield from sublist) or True)
```

---

Apparently the original generator can be simplified to this, omitting the last `and False`:

```
(None for sublist in g if (yield from sublist) )
```

---

**Revision:**

Thanks to Martijn Pieters fighting my stubbornness, I managed to see that `(None for sublist in g if (yield from sublist) and False)` and `(None for sublist in g if (yield from sublist) )` are **not equivalent**. Here an example of a `g` which makes a difference:

```
def f():
    yield 1
    return 2

def g():
    yield f()

a = (None for sublist in g() if (yield from sublist) )
for x in a: print(x)
a = (None for sublist in g() if (yield from sublist) and False)
for x in a: print(x)
```

This prints:

```
1
None
1
```

Comment: aka `itertools.chain`…

Comment: `yield from` in the if clause in a generator expression.  I didn't expect that.  Can you think of any cool uses for it that aren't adequately covered by different spellings?

Comment: So, `yield from` in the `if` evaluates to Falsy?

Comment: @thefourtheye Looks like. The question is why should it evaluate to anything Truey, if it doesn't "return" anything.

Comment: @thefourtheye it evaluates to `None` I suppose.

Comment: @alecxe My suspicion exactly. Maybe we could examine the stack after a `yield` statement.

Comment: It evaluates to false, but it also yields a value.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski How do you know it evaluates to False, and not maybe to None?

Comment: don't you want it to evaluate to 'False'? the `42`/`None` is completely irrelevant - the `and False` keeps that value from ever being returned; only the 'yield from sublist` result is ever returned.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The point is that the trailing `and False` of the original code snippet might be superfluous.

Comment: and I don't think it is... the point of the `and False` is to ensure that the `None` at the beginning never gets returned.

Comment: @Corley Could you provide an example for `g` where `(None for g in g if (yield from g) and False)` and `(None for g in g if (yield from g))` yield different results?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: if `g` is a generator that uses a `return` statement the value is the return value of the `yield from` expression.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: so `def foo(): yield 1; return True` would be an example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The yielded values must be iterables.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: another example would be `def foo(): yield 1; raise StopIteration(True)`; `return` sets the value of the `StopIteration` raised when the generator ends, or you can raise `StopIteration` with a value explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also using `def foo(): yield [1]; return 'Done'` doesn't make a difference with or without `and False`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49259/discussion-between-hyperboreus-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: @Hyperboreus: See http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions; *When the underlying iterator is complete, the value attribute of the raised `StopIteration` instance becomes the value of the yield expression. It can be either set explicitly when raising `StopIteration`, or automatically when the sub-iterator is a generator (by returning a value from the sub-generator).*

Comment: would you mind including the output of those `print`s in the answer, for education of those not running python 3.3+ yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for this amazing discussion! I added a specific example in the question. Did I summarize this about right?

Comment: @Cole Maybe your example would be more to the point if some of the inner generators had a return value, hence demonstrating the point of silencing the returns. Look at my last code snippet.

Comment: @Cole: well, you cannot use `xrange()` in Python 3. And the whole point revolves around nested *generators*, not just iterators.